On the construction of quantum circuits for S-boxes with different criteria based on the SAT solver
I'm reading this paper: On the construction of quantum circuits for
S-boxes with different criteria based on the SAT
solver. Here's the link: https://eprint.iacr.org/2024/565.pdf#page=29&zoom=100,133,636
I understand how to encoded the problem. But how do we use this in a SAT Solver, for example, Z3 model. In other word, how can i write a program to actually solve this problem? Thank you.
